# If $a$ is a positive constant no matter how small, is $x^a$ eventually larger than $\log x$?

Tags: functions

If $a$ is a positive constant no matter how small, is $x^a$ eventually larger than $\log x$?

Specifically I tried plotting $f(x)=x^a$ for $a = 0.07$ and $g(x)=\log x$ but it showed $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for large $x$ on a large interval.

Comment: Yes. One way of doing this is via computing the limit of the quotient $x^a/\log x$ although the standard calculus formalism does need justification. Maybe there is a simple algebraic proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This follows from L'Hopital's rule:$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^a}{\log x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{ax^{a-1}}{1/x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}ax^a=\infty,$$since $a>0$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to see this is to find the limit of the ratio of the functions at infinity:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^a}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\log x)'}{(x^a)'}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac1x}{ax^{a-1}}
=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{ax^a}=0
$$
for any positive $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the multi-branched [Lambert W function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), we can explicitly solve for $x$ in
$$x^a = \log x$$

Let $x = e^y$
$$e^{ay}=y$$
$$a = \frac{\log y}y$$
Let $y=e^{-u}$
$$-a=ue^u$$
$$W(-a)=u$$
Thus
$$y=\exp(-W(-a))$$
and
$$x=\exp(\exp(-W(-a)))$$

Clearly, at $x=1$, $x^a > \log x$. The $W_0$ branch tells us where $x^a$ goes below $\log x$, and the $W_{-1}$ branch shows us where $x^a$ overtakes $\log x$.

For $a = 0.07$, these solutions are (approximately)
$$x=2.94000454319605, \log x=1.07841112665417$$
and
$$x=1.55857105089153\times 10^{25}, \log x=58.0083967333164$$

Here is the [Sage / Python code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdjcEKwkAMRO_9imFPCbSyngRB8EsqUXeltLZl2WI-3wREwYEhMO9BzsNcU5Fbbe4pI5PghLiLBz42sOSlYMQwg2KLbv9ZPZuJ3STPayr18qLRsPCXqtGkK3k3_u1rsX8uBw0t9B8E7cX3XsyYlgfcskvK_AYphiqS&lang=sage) I used for those calculations.